# How to connect PHP to SQL Server?

Tags: programming-languages, php, sql, sql-server

I'm trying to connect to SQL Server using PHP, I'm learning this language.

I have read that probably a ODBC connection is the best, I have created mine ODBC but I don't know how to use it from PHP, so far I'm trying this:

```
$server = 'MyServer\MyDB';

// Connect to MSSQL
$link = mssql_connect=($server, 'MyUser', '');

if (!$link) {
    die('You cannot connect to MSSQL');
}
```

When running this I get this message:

> *OBJECT NOT FOUND, ERROR 404.*

But ODBC test is fine.

The SQL Server is located in the same PC, so maybe I don't need to input the IP.

Is there anybody who can help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears you may have a typo. Here's an example from [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-connect.php):

```
// Server in the this format: <computer>\<instance name> or 
// <server>,<port> when using a non default port number
$server = 'KALLESPC\SQLEXPRESS';

// Connect to MSSQL
$link = mssql_connect($server, 'sa', 'phpfi');

if (!$link) {
    die('Something went wrong while connecting to MSSQL');
}
```

You mistakenly placed an `=` after `mssql_connect`, attempting to make an assignment (as far as the interpreter is concerned).

As for *using* MSSql with PHP, have a look at the relevant [mssql functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.mssql.php). Next you would [select your database](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-select-db.php), and then begin [querying it](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-query.php).

Comment: Shouldn't it be "as far as the interpreter is concerned" rather than compiler?